# Hidden message box and giving an error on it

Tags: c#, debugging, error-handling

I was debugging a program and placed a message box using
`System.Windows.Messagebox.show("Message");`
I successfully debugged it, and removed all the messages created by me. 
when I tried to run it, one of the message boxes was still visible, and when ok was clicked, there is the same error all the time now and I can't get rid of it.
this is the method in which it is stopping

```
 OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
 fileDialog.Filter = "CSV Files|*.csv";
 fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
 fileDialog.Title = "Load CSV file";

 List<List<string>> listOfPreview = new List<List<string>>();

 **if (fileDialog.ShowDialog().Value)** this is the line of the error
   {
      listOfPreview = viewModel.ImportPreviewCsv(fileDialog.FileName, ',');
   }
```

the error is:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled.

Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.

Now when im trying to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find the message box I cant find it anywhere. and my program is still not working. please help.

Comment: Are you running this code on a thread?  That's not legal, OpenFileDialog must be displayed on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

the way you handle the ShowDialog is wrong,

You should just replace:

```
**if (fileDialog.ShowDialog().Value)**
```

with:

```
if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
```

Comment: it's because it's in wpf? because as you told me is not working

Answer (score 0):

Run your program in Debug mode by hitting F5 while in Visual Studio. When MessageBox comes, hit 'Pause' button on the toolbar in visual studio. Pause button will look like this '||'

Now see the Call Stack window. You will be able to find out that from where MessageBox was shown.

Comment: it is saying: There is no source code available for the current location. but it is being called from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.Filter = "CSV Files|*.csv";
fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
fileDialog.Title = "Load CSV file";

List<List<string>> listOfPreview = new List<List<string>>();

if (fileDialog.ShowDialog()!= DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    listOfPreview = viewModel.ImportPreviewCsv(fileDialog.FileName, ',');
}
```

or

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.Filter = "CSV Files|*.csv";
fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
fileDialog.Title = "Load CSV file";

List<List<string>> listOfPreview = new List<List<string>>();

if (fileDialog.ShowDialog()!= DialogResult.Ok)
{
    listOfPreview = viewModel.ImportPreviewCsv(fileDialog.FileName, ',');
}
```

Comment: ok like this it worked but the message box is shown anyway, and the error is still showing and the program still crushing